# Best Loading Screen

Tags: design, user-perception

I have always been a fan of what developers use as their loading screens.

I've always enjoyed unique ones that give me something to look at while I'm waiting, rather than a bar measuring the data loaded.

Though I understand that a loading bar could give the user a better idea of the progress but an interesting design could entertain them as they wait.

So what have you found gives the best user experience for a loading screen? Maybe some examples.

Someone with experience with this topic could give a calculated answer depending on what they found with users, rather than their own opinion.

To focus the question and make it less opinion based, does the user want to know his/her loading progress more than be entertained for those short moments of a loading screen?

Comment: Icon suggestions are off topic on this site. see http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: There is no 'best' loading screen. If there were then everything would be the same. It's going to depend on your specific situation and the information you need to get across to your users.

Comment: I think that you guys have gave a specific answer that is based on your experience or feedback from users. I agree that opinion is involved but I think it should not be put on hold, someone could have better experience then us and some research where users do actually like seeing the progress more than a fancy design.

Comment: This one is my personal favorite: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Fvi_SIQcOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends wildly on what you're trying to communicate to the user. Some might have a cool calculated feel, others might have a warm inviting feel. If you're being more cool and calculated I'd say give your users more information. This question doesn't have enough information to be answered what the "best loading icon" because there is none, there is only the best loading icon/screen for your application.

Comment: I suppose the estimated loading time also plays a factor in the decision. If you are anticipating an average wait time of less than 2 seconds (or so) then an interesting/amusing/engaging loading display will be lost as the average user will not have time to appriciate it before it disapears